# Google Earth Engine multiple filters on date

Tags: javascript, python, google-earth-engine

Using Google Earth engine API, I can filter the start and end date of a satellite data. In this code for example, I can retrieve ASTER information between January 1st 2018 to July 15th 2018.

```js
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ASTER/AST_L1T_003')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-08-15'));
var falseColor = dataset.select(['B3N', 'B02', 'B01']);
var falseColorVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 255.0,
};
Map.setCenter(-122.0272, 39.6734, 11);
Map.addLayer(falseColor.median(), falseColorVis, 'False Color');
```

What I need to do, is to retrieve data between 2010 to 2020 but in summers only. Definitely, when I apply multiple `ee.Filter.date` filters, it returns nothing since summers of every year, doesn't have overlaps. Is there any way to have multiple `OR` filters or somehow exclude the fall and winter from my retrieved data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my discoveries. In Google Earth Engine's `javascript` api, you can find the following filter:

```js
ee.Filter.dayOfYear(start, end)
```

And fix the problem as

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ASTER/AST_L1T_003')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-08-15'));
var falseColor = dataset.select(['B3N', 'B02', 'B01']);
var falseColorVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 255.0,
};
Map.setCenter(-122.0272, 39.6734, 11);
Map.addLayer(falseColor.median(), falseColorVis, 'False Color');
```

But in `python` api, it was not possible as I guess some functions were not implemented. So, one possible alternative is to use `ee.filter.OR()` to add a filter of multiple dates like:

```py
    filterSummer = ee.Filter.Or(
        ee.Filter.date('2004-06-01', '2004-10-01'),
        ee.Filter.date('2005-06-01', '2005-10-01'),
        ee.Filter.date('2006-06-01', '2006-10-01'),        
        ee.Filter.date('2007-06-01', '2007-10-01')                
    )
```

and then apply it on `ImageCollection()` class:

```py
        dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ASTER/AST_L1T_003') \
            .filterDate(start, end) \
            .filter(filterSummer)\
            .filterBounds(roi)\
            .filterMetadata('CLOUDCOVER', 'less_than', cloud_filter)
```